# Running opencv executable from another computer

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, executable

I have created a opencv proj in Ubuntu 12.04. I want to to just send the executable and the needed files to another pc. How is possible? What I should include with the executable? Is it necessary to include files from opencv library?? I found that I must have, statical linking when builting the opencv library. I have used the above file for installing opencv that I have found in documentation:

```
version="$(wget -q -O - http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix | egrep -m1 -o '\"[0-9](\.[0-9])+' | cut -c2-)"
echo "Installing OpenCV" $version
mkdir OpenCV
cd OpenCV
echo "Removing any pre-installed ffmpeg and x264"
sudo apt-get -qq remove ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev
echo "Installing Dependenices"
sudo apt-get -qq install libopencv-dev build-essential checkinstall cmake pkg-config yasm libtiff4-dev libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libdc1394-22-dev libxine-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev python-dev python-numpy libtbb-dev libqt4-dev libgtk2.0-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev x264 v4l-utils ffmpeg
echo "Downloading OpenCV" $version
wget -O OpenCV-$version.tar.gz  http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/$version/opencv-"$version".tar.gz/download
echo "Installing OpenCV" $version
tar -xvf OpenCV-$version.tar.gz
cd opencv-$version
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D  BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D  INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
make -j2
sudo make install
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
sudo ldconfig
echo "OpenCV" $version "ready to be used"
```

Is it necessary to build again opencv? How can I achieve statical linking??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run:

```
ldd <your executable name>
```

To get the list of all the shared libraries your project depends on.

Copy the libraries to the target PC.

On the target PC you need to define an env variable:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<location of all the libraries your project depends on>
```

And the run the executable in the same shell.

**EDIT:**

In case you want to compile OpenCV static libs, use:

cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ...

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L162

Hope it helps...

Comment: Yea, not the solution I am looking for. I want to statical link the executable with libs so as to be possible to run the executable in another pc without having installed the opencv library.

Comment: Yea but where I ve got to place it? In which line, or it doesn't matter??

Comment: Pass it as a comment to cmake. See my edit.